# Using Entity Framework 6 and modifying a record EntityState.Modified not being set

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using the following code to update a record in a table using EF6 the record updates but the EntityState.Modified is not true.

```
var result = dbContext.MyUsers.Find(8);
result.UserName = "Tony Baloney";
db.SaveChanges();
```

The record is updated as expected but I have overrode `SaveChanges` to check and see if a record is added or updated so that I can add either a create date or modified date as appropriate.
When adding the `EntityState.Added` is true but when updating using the above code the `EntityState.Modified` is not true.
**Why is this?**

My SaveChanges override code is:

```
 public override int SaveChanges()
    {
       ObjectContext context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
       var objectStateEntries = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
            .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship && e.Entity != null && typeof(EntityBase).IsAssignableFrom(e.Entity.GetType()))
            .ToList();

        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (var entry in objectStateEntries)
        {
            var entityBase = entry.Entity as EntityBase;
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entityBase.CreateDate = currentTime;
            }
            entityBase.UpdateDate = currentTime;
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: What is the state of result?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question or know how to determine that. I am assuming Modified based on the line above where I change the value username

Comment: You can check if it is present in objectStateEntries. If yes, it is modified.

Comment: It is null in objectStateEntries.

Answer (score 1):

To get the override of SaveChanges to work I had to add

```
context.DetectChanges();
```

after instantiating the context (second line of the override) before checking the Entity state. This then allowed the Entity state to be seen correctly. Without adding the detect changes line the EntityState had to be specifically set in the calling code.